# Wrong Pointcloud Orientation in Rviz

Tags: gazebo, rviz, transform, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey, I am trying to correctly orient the pointcloud data coming from a Kinect 3D camera sensor Gazebo model into the Rviz, but it's not working.

In Gazebo, a **Pose** is of the form:

```
<pose> x y z roll pitch yaw </pose>
```

But, input to the **static_transform_publisher** node is of the form:

```
static_transform_publisher x y z yaw pitch roll frame_id child_frame_id period_in_ms
```

I tried both the forms, but the pointcloud orientation is still incorrect. I have attached the output of both the versions below.

**Kinect's Gazebo model**

```
<model name="kinect">
      <static>true</static>
      <pose>1.274070 -0.011558 1.961223 0.021866 0.611102 -3.121294</pose>
      <link name="link">
        <inertial>
          <mass>0.1</mass>
        </inertial>
        <collision name="collision">
          <geometry>
            <box>
              <size>0.073000 0.276000 0.072000</size>
            </box>
          </geometry>
        </collision>
        <visual name="visual">
          <geometry>
            <mesh>
              <uri>model://kinect/meshes/kinect.dae</uri>
            </mesh>
          </geometry>
        </visual>
        <sensor name='camera' type='depth'>
          <update_rate>20</update_rate>
          <camera name='__default__'>
            <horizontal_fov>1.0472</horizontal_fov>
            <image>
              <width>640</width>
              <height>480</height>
              <format>R8G8B8</format>
            </image>
            <clip>
              <near>0.05</near>
              <far>3</far>
            </clip>
          </camera>
          <plugin name="kinect_camera_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_openni_kinect.so">
            <baseline>0.1</baseline>
            <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
            <updateRate>15.0</updateRate>
            <cameraName>camera</cameraName>
            <imageTopicName>/camera/rgb/image_raw</imageTopicName>
            <cameraInfoTopicName>/camera/rgb/camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
            <depthImageTopicName>/camera/depth_registered/image_raw</depthImageTopicName>
            <depthImageCameraInfoTopicName>/camera/depth_registered/camera_info</depthImageCameraInfoTopicName>
            <pointCloudTopicName>/camera/depth_registered/points</pointCloudTopicName>
            <frameName>camera_rgb_optical_frame</frameName>
            <distortion_k1>0.00000001</distortion_k1>
            <distortion_k2>0.00000001</distortion_k2>
            <distortion_k3>0.00000001</distortion_k3>
            <distortion_t1>0.00000001</distortion_t1>
            <distortion_t2>0.00000001</distortion_t2>
            <pointCloudCutoff>0.35</pointCloudCutoff>
            <pointCloudCutoffMax>4.5</pointCloudCutoffMax>
            <CxPrime>0</CxPrime>
            <Cx>0</Cx>
            <Cy>0</Cy>
            <focalLength>0</focalLength>
            <hackBaseline>0</hackBaseline>
          </plugin>
        </sensor>
        <self_collide>0</self_collide>
        <kinematic>0</kinematic>
      </link>
    </model>
```

**World to camera_rgb_optical_frame transform using TF**

```
<node   name="kinect_static_transform_publisher"    
        pkg="tf" 
        type="static_transform_publisher" 
        args="1.274070 -0.011558 1.961223 0.021866 0.611102 -3.121294 world camera_rgb_optical_frame 100"/>
```

[image: image description]

```
<node   name="kinect_static_transform_publisher"    
            pkg="tf" 
            type="static_transform_publisher" 
            args="1.274070 -0.011558 1.961223 -3.121294 0.611102 0.021866 world camera_rgb_optical_frame 100"/>
```

[image: image description]

I would really appreciate some help/guidance on this issue.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/415533/wrong-pointcloud-orientation-in-rviz/) by [Anubhav Singh](https://answers.ros.org/users/44804/anubhav-singh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2023-05-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This behaviour is perfectly normal according to the axis convention specified in [REP 103](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html).
The correction for camera optical transforms is `-90°, 0°, -90°` in the roll, pitch and yaw rotations specified in the [Suffix Frames](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html#suffix-frames) section.

- First, publish a transform from `/world` to your Kinect ( say `/camera_link`):

  ```
   <!-- publish tf from world to the kinect_camera (camera_link) -->
   <node name="kinect_static_transform_publisher" pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher"
     args="1.274070 -0.011558 1.961223 -3.121294 0.611102 0.021866 world camera_link 100" />
  ```
- Finally, publish the correct optical transform from `/camera_link` to `camera_rgb_optical_frame`:

  ```
   <!-- publish tf from camera_link to camera_rgb_optical_frame -->
   <node name="kinect_optical_transform" pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher"
     args="0 0 0 -1.5707 0 -1.5707 camera_link camera_rgb_optical_frame 100" />
  ```

---

Originally posted by [Gaurav Gupta](https://answers.ros.org/users/72874/gaurav-gupta/) with karma: 276 on 2023-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Anubhav Singh](https://answers.ros.org/users/44804/anubhav-singh/) on 2023-05-18**:
Thanks for the help.